# How to AUTOINCREMENT against another column rather than the whole table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I'm using a table to track messages sent in several different channels.

I'd like to be able to track the index of each message on a per-channel basis. 'index' is a forbidden word in SQLite so here I'll use 'id' instead.

Here's an example of the end result that I'm looking for:

```
┌───────┬────────────┬────┬───────────────────┐
│ rowid │ channel_id │ id │       text        │
├───────┼────────────┼────┼───────────────────┤
│     1 │          1 │  1 │ Hello!            │
│     2 │          1 │  2 │ Message text      │
│     3 │          1 │  3 │ Beep boop         │
│     4 │          2 │  1 │ Different channel │
│     5 │          2 │  2 │ So id has reset   │
└───────┴────────────┴────┴───────────────────┘
```

I should then be able to `INSERT INTO messages(channel, text)` and have `id` fill itself.

Normally I'd use `id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` or `id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT`. However, I believe that this increments the id per-table, not per-channel.

Is there a way that I can make the id increment only such that it creates unique combinations with another column?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a `view` on top of the table.

The `view` uses the analytic function `row_number()` to provide what you needed.  You'll need a column to sort on.  That could be your `AUTOINCREMENT` column.

https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

```
select channel_id, text
  ,row_number() over (partition by channel_id order by identity_column) as id
from unnamed_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would `identity_column` be in this case? (`view` is new terminology to me, sorry!)

Comment: Additionally, would this view be saved and accessible alongside other tables, or would I need to create it each time I query it?